# How do I fix the issue "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using a Mac. I have Anaconda installed. When I type import numpy or import matplotlib I don't run into any issues. The only issue I'm having is with sklearn. 
I'm fairly new to CS/ DS. Any help/ tips is greatly appreciated.

I've tried uninstalling sklearn and reinstalling. I've pretty much tried every solution on StackOverflow. The only thing I haven't tried is reinstalling anaconda.

import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import sklearn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

I expect to get no result just like with matplotlib and numpy which means everything works, but in lieu of that I get that output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have sklearn installed? It should be in some requirement, but it seems that someone needs it as a dependency and does not find it.

```
pip freeze | grep sklearn
```

It will tell you if you have it installed.
Do you work in a virtualenv?
If you do not have it installed try to do it and if not, pass the traceback.

if you work on mac you can also try updating xcode and updating yourself pip

```
xcode-select --install

pip install --upgrade pip
```